# Collation works on mongo but not in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, collation

I have created an index on a field using the collation { "locale": "fr", "strength": 2 }

When using GUI tools such as Robo3T and NoSQL Manager, the case-insensitive queries work as intended:

```
db.getCollection('the_collection_name').find({title_fr: "some Title"}).collation({ "locale": "fr", "strength": 2 })
```

But when I do the very same query in Node 10.16.0, using mongoose 5.6.7, the query is case sensitive.

The mongoose query goes like this:

```
const condition = { title_fr: title };
const collation = { "locale": "fr", "strength": 2 };

AllTheBooks
    .find(condition, null, collation)
    .exec( (err: Error, found_books: Array<any>) => { ...
```

I read the few q&a here and found that I had to check those two parameters but they were already ok:

- db.version() : 3.6.13
- featureCompatibilityVersion: 3.6

Any idea on how to activate the use of the collation in mongoose?

Comment: Could you show your mongoose query.

Comment: Yes, I should have included it. I just edited the question.

Comment: Try this way `AllTheBooks.find(condition).collation({ "locale": "fr", "strength": 2 })`.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks!

Comment: Still, this looks more like a bug. According to the documentation, my query should have worked fine: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions [at the bottom, it specifies that collation can be used as an option).

Comment: No pls check again,  these are the prototype options not the arguments. I will post an answer for this.